# XSL - copy element with attribute and exclude particular child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML below.

```
<rootElement rootAttribute1="value1" rootAttribute2="value2">
    <childElement childElementAttribute="value">
        <grandChild>First</grandChild>
    </childElement>
    <childElement childElementAttribute="copyMe">
        <grandChild>Second</grandChild>
    </childElement>
    <childElement childElementAttribute="value">
        <grandChild>Third</grandChild>
    </childElement>
</rootElement>
```

And I need process it via XSL, applying next reules:
1. rootElement element should be copied with all it's attributes
2. rootElement element, that was just copied, should contain only childElement elements that have childElementAttribute="copyMe" (string to compare "copyMe" just in this case, but it is generated dinamically) (with all their attributes).
"copyMe" here is just particular value, but 
So, above example should be transformed in next one

```
<rootElement rootAttribute1="value1" rootAttribute2="value2">
    <childElement childElementAttribute="copyMe">
        <grandChild>Second</grandChild>
    </childElement>
</rootElement>
```

Here is the XSL I tried

```
<!-- Copy rootElement element-->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="copyAndExclude">
    <xsl:param name="requiredAttrivuteValue"/>
    <xsl:if test="childElement[@childElementAttribute=$requiredAttrivuteValue]" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="excludeUnnecessaryChilds" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- exclude unnecessary child elements-->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="excludeUnnecessaryChilds">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="excludeUnnecessaryChilds" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    ....
    <xsl:apply-templates select="rootElement" mode="copyAndExclude" >
        <xsl:with-param name="requiredAttrivuteValue" select="$someValue"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
<xsl:template>

Here someValue is generated dinamically and depends on few things, that are not significant here
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the XSLT have you have already tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need modes, simply start with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then exclude the elements you don't want to copied with

```
<xsl:template match="childElement[not(@childElementAttribute = 'copyMe')]"/>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for response. Modes are required here because xml that I posted is only part of all document. So I need to be sure that template will not be applied to other elements.

Comment: Also I need to retireve soveValue vrom a variable.
I updated info in question. Thank you!